# C header file won't compile with C, but will with C++

Tags: c++, c, header, compiler-errors

I have the following chunk of a header file BKE_mesh.h:

```
/* Connectivity data */
typedef struct IndexNode {
    struct IndexNode *next, *prev;
    int index;
} IndexNode;
void create_vert_face_map(ListBase **map, IndexNode **mem, const struct MFace *mface,
          const int totvert, const int totface);
void create_vert_edge_map(ListBase **map, IndexNode **mem, const struct MEdge *medge,
          const int totvert, const int totedge);
```

Note that the header file was prepared for the possibility of being used in a C++ file, as it had:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

at the top of the file, and the needed finish at the bottom.  But the class implementing it was written in C.

Next, whenever I try to #include the header file, I get an odd error.  If the file has a .cpp extension, it compiles just fine, no complaints whatsoever.  However, if I do:

```
#include "BKE_mesh.h"
```

inside of a file with a .c extension, I get the following errors:

```
expected ')' before '*' token
```

for the two last functions, in specific, the variable:

```
ListBase **map
```

in both classes. (Note that earlier in the header file, it declared, but not defined ListBase).

So, my question is:  why is this valid C++ code, but not C code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++ you can refer to struct names directly but in C you need to prepend the keyword `struct`.

```
void create_vert_face_map(struct ListBase **map, ... );
```

You could get around this by adding a typedef. Then you wouldn't have to modify the function declaration.

```
typedef struct ListBase ListBase;
```

Comment: /me slaps his head.  Thanks.  I think that's it.  (ListBase was defined like this: struct ListBase;).  It makes me wonder than how this works as a C file...Oh, also, shouldn't wrapping that in extern "C" { ... } cause it to have those same errors?  Thank you.

Comment: Some C compilers used to autodetect this mistake back in the day. Some people used to compile there "C" libraries as if they were C++ with C linkage.

Comment: @Leif Anderson: Wrapping the file in extern "C" { } does nothing except change how the linker works. You seem to be under the impression that C/C++ are the similar. Fortunately C++ is a completely different language and should be treated as such. Java has the same basic semantics as C but you don't consider the two languages to be interchangeable!

Comment: @Marin.  Ah, okay.  I thought it actually used a C compiler, okay.  Also, I was mainly intrigued that it didn't work as C code, because that's what it was originally, I wouldn't have posted this if it was the other way around (worked as C code, but not as C++ code).

Answer (score 0):

Try running just the pre-processor for each case.
Comparing the result may show different header files.
If so, it may hint on the "C"-problem.